# How can you do a str.replace when you have slash and backslash

Tags: javascript

This is my string:

```
myStr = "this/is/foo/bar"
```

I want it to be

```
myStr = "thisisfoobar"
```

But this attempt only removes the first /

```
myStr.replace("/", "");
```

How do you get it to replace all of them?

Comment: `myStr.replace(/\//g , "");`

Comment: it works, thanks satpal :)